# Python keyboard event does not respect layout

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I have a problem with win32api.keybd_event in python (see script below):

Under EN layout the script press "q" key then "1" key (seems ok).

Under FR layout the script press "q" key then "&" key (instead of "a" and "&").

It looks strange that the layout translation is partialy done.

Here is the test sample:

```
import win32api
import ctypes
import win32con
import time

def play(vk):
    s = ctypes.windll.user32.MapVirtualKeyA(vk, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(vk, s, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win32api.keybd_event(vk, s, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    time.sleep(0.7)

vk_key_Q = int('0x51', 16)
vk_key_1 = int('0x31', 16)

while True:
    play(vk_key_Q)
    play(vk_key_1)
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

My bet is you need to pass through [`TranslateMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Win32 API.  According to the Windows docs, just firing a keyboard event doesn't map the event through the keyboard layout; that needs to be done separately with `TranslateMessage`, which applications need to do explicitly if they choose to work at that low a level.  I'm not sure that `win32api` has that method available, but reading around, it looks like `win32gui` does.